# PyQt RichText Formatting in system tray tooltip

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, tooltip, richtext

This is an example of code for simple system tray PyQt application.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def main():
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

   trayIcon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon('test.png'), app)
   menu = QtGui.QMenu()
   exitAction = menu.addAction("Exit")
   trayIcon.setContextMenu(menu)

   # I'd like to show picture in tooltip, BUT IT'S NOT WORK IN WINDOWS
   trayIcon.setTooltip('<img src="SomePicture.png" width="48" height="48"/>')

   trayIcon.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

In this code I'd like to show balloon tooltip with a some picture and some kind of text formating. For this purpose I use RichText tags formatting. As the result for Ubuntu Linux system (Gnome desktop) everything is Ok. But when I try use RichText formatting for tooltip in Windows XP system, nothing works. Tooltip text equals source string: ''.
Python version on Windows 2.7, on Linux 2.6 but I think that problem is not in different versions.

If in Windows OS RichText isn't parsing how can I make same kind of GUI (Crossplatform is prefered)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone also interested in create of balloon widget. This my code:

```
class SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, parent = None): 
        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        traySignal = "activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)"
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL(traySignal), self._activateRoutine)
        self.balloon = balloonWidget(name)

    def _activateRoutine(self, reason):
        if reason == QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger:
            self.balloon.show(self.geometry())

class balloonWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,name):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent = None, flags = QtCore.Qt.Popup)

        self.name = name

        self.offsetX = 10
        self.offsetY = 10

        self.outInfo = QtGui.QLabel(self)

        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget {border:5px solid rgb(170, 170, 255);}")

    def show(self,coord):
        richText = tr('Any text with Rich Format')
        self.outInfo.setText(richText)
        self.outInfo.show()
        self.adjustSize()

        origin = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().bottomRight()

        if coord.y() < origin.y()/2:
            moveY = coord.bottomLeft().y() + self.offsetY
        else:
            moveY = coord.topLeft().y() - (self.height() + self.offsetY)

        if coord.x() + self.width() + self.offsetX >= origin.x():
            moveX = origin.x() - (self.width() + self.offsetX)
        else:
            moveX = coord.x()

        self.move(moveX,moveY)
        self.setVisible(True)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()
        self.hide()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.close()
```

Comment: Isn't the first line in `ballonWidget.__init__` indented by one extra level?

Comment: I tried it and it worked once I removed the call to `tr` in the `show` method (assigning the string directly instead).

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake as your first comment: of course indent was wrong (I've fixed). `tr` method won't work if you not setup Qt translator: you can set it for UTF-8 encoding: `QtCore.QTextCodec.setCodecForTr(QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("UTF-8"))`

Comment: +1 Ok, thanks for letting me know. I'm completely new to this framework.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows Qt uses the os' tooltip system, which only supports text.

If you want something more advanced, you could [`QSystemTrayIcon.showMessage()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qsystemtrayicon.html#showMessage) use as described [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/desktop-systray.html). You'll probably have to install an eventfilter or override the `QTrayIcon`s `event` method to get the help event.

Comment: Thank you for help, but unfortunately QSystemTrayIcon.showMessage() can show only plain text and doesn't support RichText 
"Shows a balloon message for the entry with the given title, message and icon for the time specified in millisecondsTimeoutHint. title and message must be plain text strings". 
Also MessageIcon is the enum, so only standard pictures can be used. May be is some other decision exist?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of would be to create a frameless widget an show that.